# Insert query not working in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $hostname = "localhost"; 

 //connection to the database
 $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

if ($dbhandle) {
     echo 'conected';
} else {
      echo 'not conected WITH DATABASE';
}

mysql_select_db('data');

$indentdata= "INSERT INTO indentname ( deskno, fileno, indentdate, receivedate, indentorid, projectleaderid, division, estimatedcost, convertedcost, item, projectno, cprojectno, projectname, budgethead, cashcode, nature, is_delete) VALUES ( '".$_POST['deskno']."','".$_POST['fileno']." ', '".$_POST['indentdate']." ', ' ".$_POST['receivedate']." ', ' ".$_POST['indentorname']." ' , ' ".$_POST['projectleader']." ' , ' ".$_POST['estimatedcost']." ', ' ".$_POST['convertedtedcost']." ' , ' ".$_POST['item']." ', ' ".$_POST['projectno']." ', ' ".$_POST['conprojectno']."',' ".$_POST['projectname']." ',' ".$_POST['budgethead']." ',' ".$_POST['cashcode']." ',' ".$_POST['nature']." ',0 )";
       mysql_query($indentdata);
```

Here, I have tried out above code for insert. But Insert query is not working.Plese give me suggestions for the insert. Record is not Inserted but also not giving any error

Comment: ever hear of sql injection! this is a nice example. are you connected to db?

Comment: agreed, but to answer the question..are you able to connect, select data or insert into any database table?

Comment: First of all, stop using mysql_* functions. They are deprecated since 2 years and not longer supported. Use mysqli_* or PDO_* instead. Second point, you should take a look at prepared statements. When you do it this way, you're database can be hacked in a few seconds with SQL injections.
Btw: You have 17 attributes, but only 16 values. No value for attribute "division"

Comment: there are 17 column fields and 15 values. Good Job !!

Comment: @Plum There are 16 ;) At the end, there is a 0. It has also to be count as a value :)

Comment: @Twinfriends yes. then what about the 17th value. Did Rasmus Ledorf Took it?

Comment: @Plum As you can see in my comment above, i've already figgured out. The value for "division" is missing. And calm down. I just said that the 0 is also a value and there are 16, not 15. No need to go in ragemode.

Comment: For future reference, usage of [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) would help you troubleshoot your queries on your own. General `error_reporting(E_ALL);` could also come in handy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is, you have specified 17 columns but providing values for only 16 of them.

Comment: Thats worth a comment, but not an answer.

Comment: @Twinfriends. No, with context to the question yes it's an answer.

Comment: It is an answer